# Is there a specific word for a genius who can express themselves via original insights?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for a genius who can express themselves via original insights?

I want to say that

> there are no ____ in the arts anymore, it's impossible

An idiom would be fine.

---

Perhaps there is some synonym of 'self expression'

> the expression of one's feelings, thoughts, or ideas, especially in writing, art, music, or dance

which forms an idiom with 'genius'?

The closest I myself can think of is some variant of heurēka, "I have found it".

---

'Creative genius' almost works, but I don't think that it excludes genius that is not self expression. None of the other synonyms, that I know, exclude everything but creative genius.

Comment: An "outside-the-box thinker"? How about "a paradigm changer"?

Comment: the second one is better, but has to be aesthetic! @rhetorician

Comment: Perhaps a [*singular genius*](http://theadventurehandbook.com/the-art-of-collaboration-and-the-myth-of-singular-genius/)

Comment: @Clare not sure why an example sentence would help, as i've stated what i want to say

Comment: I don't understand why 'geniuses' doesn't work. So it's still unclear. Don't all geniuses  express themselves via original insights?

Comment: @Clare well maybe given context 'genius' would be enough, but it's not obvious that entails creativity, let alone self expression! i would add to the question, my 'reasoning', but that often means that people don't understand it. what do you think?

Comment: You need to indicate your research. Look in thesauruses and tell us exactly why the words in them don't work.

Comment: In his book "Genius" about Richard Feynman, James Gleick said (this is a paraphrase) "There are ordinary geniuses, and there are magicians. Feynman was a magician."  Feynman was a physicist, but at the level he worked, physics is also an art.

Comment: @ab2 yeah was thinking of the word 'wizard' ha

Comment: In my view *genius* has nothing to do with expression and needs nothing to do with original thought… and sorry but Clare'e entirely right to ask for an example. *There are no ____ in the arts anymore, it's impossible* might work if the phrase somehow defined the missing term.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin that's great, and why 'genius' on its own won't do

Comment: thanks for that clarification and thus more clearly, no; there is certainly no such word and almost certainly no such term.

I forgot to ask, what research have you done, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin i have tried google, and read about the arts, including 'romantic genius'. also, see my answer below

Comment: **Pariah**, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The word "epiphanic genius" appears, briefly, in the literature on the psychologist William James. Epiphany / epiphanic, defined by the ODO

> A moment of sudden and great revelation or realization.

It may cover the ideas of self expression, genius and insight.

I mean, dependent on how close 'realization' / 'revelation' / 'response' are to 'self expression'.

[image]

- Dynamic Individualism of William James, The By James O. Pawelski,
  p173

Comment: any comment on the downvote? it seems to answer my question!

Comment: Uh… sorry but no; not at all. That seems to have nothing to do with your Question.

Would you mind going right back and giving us your definition of *genius*?

Comment: why do you think it has nothing to do with my Question? @RobbieGoodwin i just mean the bog standard definition of (creative) genius e.g. "exceptional intellectual or creative power or other natural ability." not getting the sarcasm from everyone, either, i'm here to learn

Comment: You might want to take the Topic to Chat, or take terms like *genius* and *express* or *insight* to English Language Learners.

Either way please remember not all geniuses can express themselves at all, nor have original insight; very few people express themselves through insight. 

If I understood *There are no ____ in the arts* still, why would it be *impossible*; what  does *any more* add; how did *aesthetic* help?

What has *self expression* to do with *epiphany* or *realization*, with *revelation* or * response*?

The Question seemed strange; each explanation stranger…

Answer (score 1):

A [visionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visionary)

*Graham Bell was a visionary.*

> If you refer to someone as a visionary, you mean that they have strong, **original ideas** about how things might be different in the future, especially about how things might be improved.

While not exactly synonomous to '[genius](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genius)' it has some overlap.
Genius:

> Someone possessing extraordinary intelligence or skill; especially somebody who has demonstrated this by a creative or **original work** in science, music, art etc.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the noun **connoisseur** fits into the context.

*Connoisseur*: [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connoisseur)

> Expert:
>
> especially : one who understands the details, .technique, or
> principles of an art and is competent to act as a critical judge.
>
> A connoisseur of music.

Answer (score -1):

An idiom that expresses the *general* idea of the poster’s sentence is:

> Wha’s like us? Damn few, and they’re a’ deid.

This is Scots dialect: wha = who, a’ = all, died = dead.

It is part of a Burns supper toast (“Here’s to us…”). Apparently the older version is “Gey few” meaning very few, but there are gey few that speak the auld Scots tongue today.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try to find the synonyms to this word. According to [Word Panda](https://wordpanda.net/synonyms) dictionary the synonyms to the word 'genius' are acumen, knack (a special skill, talent, or aptitude) or prodigy (a person, especially a child or young person, having extraordinary talent or ability). Hope it helps.

Comment: not really, needs to be more specific.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question... that wasn't clearly asked.  Alas.